# Linq update query - Is there no pretty way?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

I want to update my database using a LINQ2SQL query.

However this seems for some reason to be a very ugly task compared to the otherwise lovely LINQ code.

The query needs to update two tables.

```
tbl_subscription
(
   id int,
   sub_name nvarchar(100),
   sub_desc nvarchar(500),
   and so on.
)

tbl_subscription2tags
(
   sub_id (FK to tbl_subscription)
   tag_id (FK to a table called tbl_subscription_tags)
)
```

Now down to my update function a send a tbl_subscription entity with the tags and everything.

I can't find a pretty way to update my database..

I can only find ugly examples where I suddenly have to map all attributes..

There most be a smart way to perform this. Please help.

C# Example if possible.

I have tried this with no effect:

```
public void UpdateSubscription(tbl_subscription subscription)
    {
        db.tbl_subscriptions.Attach(subscription);
        db.Refresh(System.Data.Linq.RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues, subscription);
        db.SubmitChanges(System.Data.Linq.ConflictMode.FailOnFirstConflict);
    }
```

Source for this code is here:
http://skyeyefive.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!6B6EB6E6694659F2!516.entry

Comment: When I say pretty I mean a way that does not involve me having to set all attributes like:
currentEntity.title = updatedEntity.title;

That kinda destroys the beauty of just beeing able to update the datacontext when making changes to the database.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't just make the changes to the objects and perform a SubmitChanges to the DataContext?

```
using(MyDataContext dc = new MyDataContext("ConnectionString"))
{
  foreach(var foo in dc.foo2)
  {
   foo.prop1 = 1;
  }
  dc.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Otherwise you need to tell us more about the lifecycle of the object you want to manipulate

edit: forgot to wrap in brackets for using

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm misunderstanding your situation, I think that citronas is right.

The **best and easiest way** that I've found to update database items through LINQ to SQL is the following:

1. **Obtain the item** you want to change from the data context
2. **Change whatever values** you want to update
3. **Call the `SubmitChanges()` method** of the data context.

---

### Sample Code

The sample code below assumes that I have a data context named `DBDataContext` that connects to a database that has a `Products` table with *ID* and *Price* parameters. Also, a `productID` variable contains the *ID* of the record you want to update.

```
using (var db = new DBDataContext())
{
    // Step 1 - get the item from the data context
    var product = db.Products.Where(p => p.ID == productID).SingleOrDefault();
    if (product == null) //Error checking
    {
        throw new ArgumentException();
    }

    // Step 2 - change whatever values you want to update
    product.Price = 100;

    // Step 3 - submit the changes
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Comment: What I don't like about this is that I have to "know" all properties. Say I add another property I have to go into the Update rutine and add it here as well.
I try to avoid this as much as possible.

Comment: @Brinth you only have to add it in the Update routine if you're changing the value of the property - there's no way around that. However, if you're not going to be updating the value of that new property, you don't have to add it to the routine.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that you can use "Attach" as seen in my question to update a table, but apparently not the sub tables. So I just used a few Attach and it worked without having to run through parameters!